# What player options, or monster traits, can/can not affect the Multiverse UA races, due to different creature type?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters, class-feature, racial-traits

In [Unearthed Arcana 2021: Travelers of the Multiverse](https://media.wizards.com/2021/dnd/downloads/UA2021_TravelersoftheMultiverse.pdf), a few of the races are singularly a type other than Humanoid. Specifically, Construct, Ooze, and Monstrosity.

What are the mechanical consequences of a player character having one of the creature types that are in this supplement?

Comment: Are you just asking for a complete list of spells and abilities that work differently for these creature types compared to humanoids? That seems too broad to be practically answerable.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson not a complete list, but perhaps significant examples, in which the use of the spell or trait in question could be radically altered.

Comment: Related: [What are the mechanical consequences of a Centaur's Fey trait?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/136750/33569)

Comment: @V2Blast I think the answers to that question are good for this one too, so I will be deleting this question within 48 hours. Just wanted to leave this up long enough for you to see my thanks.

Comment: @Journer: You don't need to delete duplicate questions - you can just leave them up so that they can serve as a signpost for future readers looking for a similar question. That said, I'm not sure this is fully a duplicate of that question; obviously, it covers the Fey aspect of your question, but there may still be room to ask if there are any player character features/spells/etc. that interact in a unique way with the Constructs, Ooze, or Monstrosity creature types, beyond them simply not being Humanoid. (That said, it may or may not be considered too broad by the community.)

Comment: As a note to others, I would argue that although there's a lot of overlap, these two are NOT duplicates. The simple fact that a Construct character is going to have a lot of issues getting a Heal spell is more than sufficient for me to deem this question unique.

Comment: It might however be somewhat wide, unless this *only* affects the UA races.

Comment: I might suggest splitting the question into 3 specific ones: one asking about character options (especially spells) that interact differently with the Construct type, and possibly one about the Ooze type and one about the Monstrosity type. ...That said, I don't think there are any class/subclass features that interact differently with PCs of any of those creature types (a D&D Beyond sitewide search filtered to "Characters" results yields nothing relevant), and I'm not sure if any spells/magic items interact differently with oozes/monstrosities, so that may be unnecessary/overkill...

Answer (score 2):

Let's do this in order of ease

### At time of posting, I could find no spells that demand a creature type of "monstrosity"

Moving on

### Oozes

**Works(Super Effective!)**

- Sunbeam (6th level)
- Sunburst (8th level)

### Constructs

**Works**

- Mending (cantrip)

**Doesn't**

- Abi-Dalzim’s Horrid Wilting (8th level)
- Antilife Shell (5th level)
- Blight (4th level)
- Cure Wounds (1st level)
- Heal (6th level)
- Healing Word (1st level)
- Mass Cure Wounds (5th level)
- Mass Heal (9th level)
- Mass Healing Word (3rd level)
- Phantasmal Force (2nd level)
- Power Word Heal (9th level)
- Prayer of Healing (2nd level)
- Spare the Dying (cantrip)

### Humanoid

I'm sure there are many posts about humanoid typing, especially for when centaur came out. I'm making another.

**Required(Works)**

- Animate Dead (3rd level)
- Calm Emotions (2nd level)
- Charm Person (1st level)
- Create Undead (3rd level)
- Crown of Madness (2nd level)
- Dominate Person (5th level)
- Hold Person (2nd level)
- Magic Jar (6th level)
- Reincarnate (5th level)
- Simulacrum (7th level)

Yes, Simulacrum can be used to target beasts as well, but as we're looking at how spells will effect these new races, it's human required.

Comment: Please use bulleted lists instead of code formatting.

Comment: Fixed it, sorry @ThomasMarkov

Comment: Thanks! Some devices don’t handle code formatting properly, so we like to avoid it when there’s no code.